# how do I WRITE (serialize) LocalDateTime as JSON String using ISO-8601 format?

Tags: json, kotlin

```kotlin
data class Task(val: name, val: dueDate: LocalDateTime)

val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
objectMapper.registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
val task = ("task", LocalDateTime.now())
val json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(task)
println(json)
```

**Actual:**
`{"name":"task","dueDate":[2023,3,11,16,1,54,728228000]}`

**Expected:**
`{"name":"task","dueDate":"2023-03-11T16:1:54.728"}`

Answer (score 0):

```
val json = ObjectMapper()
    .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
    .writeValueAsString(jsonBody)
```